# scrollviewDidEndDragging not called in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it. I want to catch the scrolling of the table using the `UIScrollViewDelegate`. The delegate of the table is properly set because I can perform `UITableView` methods but when scrolling, the method `scrollViewDidScroll` is called but `scrollViewDidEndDragging` is not called. I also implemented `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and others, but only `scrollViewDidScroll` is called. So I want to know why `scrollViewDidEndDragging` is not called.

**EDIT**

There's not much here actually, just logging the event.

**This one is called**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

DDLogVerbose(@"did scroll");

}
```

**This one is not called**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"end drag");
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I tried adding the scrollViewDidEndDragging inside my UItableview subclass, and it was works. So how do I make my viewcontroller handle the scrollViewDidEndDragging?

Comment: Update your question with actual code copy and pasted from your project. You may have a simple typo.

Comment: Could you please show your `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method.

Comment: Did you override this method in subclass and forgot to call [super xxx]?

Comment: I just wanted to check the method signature which looks good. Could you please try implementing `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and see if this gets called.

Comment: I'm not using a sublcass for this. scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is also not called. My UITableView is a subclass of STCollapseTableView but there's nothing there that's overriding the scrollViewDidEndDragging method.

Comment: I voted to close this. I'd suggest posting a bug report on the STCollapseTableView Github page that it has a bad implementation of delegate overriding.

Answer (score 1):

I created a clean project and add a tableView to test it. Here are the codes:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    NSLog(@"end drag");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"end decelerating");
}

@end
```

Here are logs after draging:

```
2015-10-09 14:21:57.442 test[85247:453953] end drag
2015-10-09 14:21:58.178 test[85247:453953] end decelerating
```

So the these methods are called.

You should paste more codes to help us to find the problem.

Comment: tableView.delegate = YourController;

Comment: The delegate is already assigned to my viewcontroller in the storyboard. Anyway, I just implemented the scrollViewDidEndDragging inside my uitableview subclass then fire a notification to inform my viewcontroller of the event.